# Fix inverted distplot when plotting distplot and boxplot together using seaborn in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

**My DataFrame is as below:-**

```
spending    advance_payments    probability_of_full_payment     current_balance     credit_limit    min_payment_amt     max_spent_in_single_shopping
0   19.94   16.92   0.8752  6.675   3.763   3.252   6.550
1   15.99   14.89   0.9064  5.363   3.582   3.336   5.144
2   18.95   16.42   0.8829  6.248   3.755   3.368   6.148
3   10.83   12.96   0.8099  5.278   2.641   5.182   5.185
4   17.99   15.86   0.8992  5.890   3.694   2.068   5.837
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
205     13.89   14.02   0.8880  5.439   3.199   3.986   4.738
206     16.77   15.62   0.8638  5.927   3.438   4.920   5.795
207     14.03   14.16   0.8796  5.438   3.201   1.717   5.001
208     16.12   15.00   0.9000  5.709   3.485   2.270   5.443
209     15.57   15.15   0.8527  5.920   3.231   2.640   5.879
```

Now I am trying to plot a boxplot on top of the displot using seaborn libraries. Distplot on its own works fine, however when I add boxplot on the same axis, the distplot gets inverted, not sure why that is happening. Can someone please help me fix this?

**Below is my code:-**

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3,figsize=(10,10))
j=0
k=0
for i in df.columns:
    sns.distplot(df[i],ax=axs[j,k],color='blue')
    sns.boxplot(df[i],ax=axs[j,k],color='green',boxprops=dict(alpha=.5))
    plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
    k=k+1
    if k==3:
        k=0
        j=j+1
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have tried `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()` but that did not help.

**Below is the output I am getting.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding different charts type on same figure is what causing you the problem, as seaborn does not handle them well. Instead, seaborn offer built-in plot options to combine different charts. In your case, you want to combine box plot with kernel estimate. Seaborn allows you to do that with [violinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html).

It can yields something like that:
[image]

(taken from documentation that a linked above)

The format looks a bit different from what you tried to do, but essentially it shows same data: frequency with boxplot.

Code for your case:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3,figsize=(10,10))
j=0
k=0
for i in df.columns:
    sns.violinplot(df[i],ax=axs[j,k],cut=0)
    k=k+1
    if k==3:
        k=0
        j=j+1
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I'm keep searching for a good reason why distplot is inverted when plotting together with boxplot. So far I couldn't find a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand a violin plot essentially represents the same thing that I am trying to plot, perhaps even a more elegant and proper way of representing the intented data. However I never found violin plots to be very intuitive and hence opted for the boxplot on top of distplot approach which to me conveyed the data in a much better manner.  Let me know if you find anything on why the distplot got inverted, I am searching the web too, I guess it might be some global settings associated with sns.boxplot which are causing this, just not able to figure it out.